# Memory leak, numerous bitmap images C++ CLI

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm getting an out of memory error.  I have one form in a picture-processing app.

Here is the relevant portion of code from a void routine:

```
Image^ CurrentImage;
Image^ ProcessedImage;
for(int i=0; i<NumSourceFiles; i++) {
   CurrentImage = Image::FromFile(File[i]);
   ProcessedImage = ProcessImage(CurrentImage, ShrinkToWidth, ShrinkToHeight, Rectangle(LeftOrigin,TopOrigin,CropWidth,CropHeight));
   NumFiles++;  //increment to get next number to save
   NextFileName = folderName_specific+"\\"+SelectedCondition+"_"+Convert::ToString(NumFiles)+".jpg";
   ProcessedImage->Save(NextFileName, ImageFormat::Jpeg);
   delete CurrentImage;
   delete ProcessedImage;
}
```

Now here is the ProcessImage routine:

```
private: Image^ ProcessImage(Image^ img, int width, int height, Rectangle cropArea)  //shrink and crop
{
   Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew Bitmap(img);
   bmpImage = bmpImage->Clone(cropArea, bmpImage->PixelFormat);
   Bitmap^ bmpImage1 = gcnew Bitmap(bmpImage, width, height);
   delete bmpImage;
   return bmpImage1;
}
```

If I get rid of all the delete statements, then it will process around 200 images before running out of memory.  If I remove the two delete statements in the void routine it will process about 300.  If I keep them all in it will do around 500 images before an out of memory failure.  It always fails at the first statement of the ProcessImage routine.

I tried making bmpImage1 a global variable and deleting it in the void routine, but that didn't help.  Any idea where I'm building up memory?

---

Update 12April2018:
I simplified this as follows (stuck it all in the for/next loop) and it STILL runs out of memory after 550 or so pictures are saved.  Stumped.... Really need to solve this... Lil' help?  (Pretty please with sugar on top!)

```
for(int i=0; i<NumSourceFiles; i++) {
    Image^ CurrentImage = Image::FromFile(File[i]);
    NumFiles++;  //increment to get next number to save
    NextFileName = folderName_specific+"\\"+SelectedCondition+"_"+Convert::ToString(NumFiles)+".jpg";
    Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew Bitmap(CurrentImage);
    bmpImage = bmpImage->Clone(Rectangle(LeftOrigin,TopOrigin,CropWidth,CropHeight), bmpImage->PixelFormat);
    Image^ ProcessedImage = gcnew Bitmap(bmpImage, ShrinkToWidth, ShrinkToHeight);
    ProcessedImage->Save(NextFileName, ImageFormat::Jpeg);
    delete bmpImage;
    delete ProcessedImage;
    delete CurrentImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding these two statements after the three delete statements:

GC::Collect();
GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();

You must use both statements in this order.  Memory leak vanquished.